# Conditional Formatting Columns in Power Bi by multiple values with tolerances

Tags: powerbi-desktop, conditional-formatting, specifications, rules, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to create a report in Power Bi. My initial table is currently populated with values and I want to conditionally format this table with very specific rules and add a tolerance.

Table
[Conditional Formatting should be reflected in this table. Current Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHjab.png)

In this table there will be specific variables that can influence the number. This table shows what the correct values are.
[Set variables and variations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nds14.png)

I tried to add the conditional formatting with colors and added the (+-)10 to the end values. But I need this to be more column specific. For example one column in the table has 85 but the set number for that should be 0 with a tolerance of +-10. So 85 should show red for that particular value. I can not predict all the possible values so its difficult to create a conditional rule that will not give off false colors.

If its possible I would like individual conditional formatting for each column. So for the value in this column would be:

=0   (green)    This should only apply to one specific column and not all in the table.

> 10  (red)
> -10 (red)

The other would be based of conditions, if it has 2 materials then value should be xx and if it has 3 then it should be xxx.